# How to mock a window variable in a single story

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I am using [Navigator online](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/onLine) in my React Application to determine if the client is online. I am showing an offline Fallback Component when the client is offline. For now I have made the Component Pure - so I can display it in Storybook by passing the online status as property. But this is not always a suitable solution.

So I wonder how can you mock global (window) variables for a single story in Storybook? The only - very dirty solution - I found looks as following:

```
ClientOffline.decorators = [
  (Story) => {
    const navigatiorInitally = global.navigator

    // I am overwritting the navigator object instead of directly the 
    // online value as this throws an 'TypeError: "x" is read-only' Error
    Object.defineProperty(global, 'navigator', {
      value: { onLine: false },
      writable: false,
    })

    useEffect(() => {
      return () => {
        Object.defineProperty(global, 'navigator', {
          value: navigatiorInitally,
          writable: false,
        })
       location.reload() //needed because otherwilse other stories throw an error
      }
    }, [])

    return <Story />
  },
]
```

Does anybody have a more straightforward solution?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What should the user see when they load this part of the page? What do they see instead? What is `Storybook`? Why is passing the online status as a property not always a suitable solution? What specific situation did you encounter where this doesn't work?

Comment: Why are you asking what `Storybook` is in a question which is tagged with `Storybook`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this answer I assume that all side effects (and communicating with Navigator is a side effect) are separated from component body into hooks.

Let's assume that you have component that looks like this:

```js
function AwesomeComponent () {
  let [connectionStatus, setConnectionStatus] = useState('unknown');
  useEffect(function checkConnection() {
    if (typeof window === 'undefined' || window.navigator.onLine) setConnectionStatus('online'); 
    else setConnectionStatus('offline');
  }, []);
  
  if (connectionStatus === 'online') return <OnlineComponent/>
  if (connectionStatus === 'offline') return <FallbackComponent/>
  return null;
}
```

Your can extract your hook into separate module. In my example it would be both - state and effect.

```js
function useConnectionStatus() {
  let [connectionStatus, setConnectionStatus] = useState("unknown");
  useEffect(function checkConnection() {
    if (typeof window === "undefined" || window.navigator.onLine)
      setConnectionStatus("online");
    else setConnectionStatus("offline");
  }, []);
  return connectionStatus;
}
```

This way you separate logic from presentation and can mock individual modules. Storybook have [guide to mock individual modules](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/workflows/build-pages-with-storybook#mocking-imports) and configure them per story. Better consult the docs, since software is changing and in time something may be done in some other way.

Let's say, you named your file `useConnectionStatus.js`. To mock it, you will have to create `__mock__` folder, create your mocked module there. For example it would be something like this:

```js
// __mock__/useConnectionStatus.js
let connectionStatus = 'online';
export default function useConnectionStatus(){
  return connectionStatus;
}

export function decorator(story, { parameters }) {
  if (parameters && parameters.offline) {
    connectionStatus = 'offline';
  }
  return story();  
}
```

Next step is to modify webpack config to use your mocked hook instead of actual hook. Documentation provide a way to do this from your `.storybook/main.js`. At the time of writing it is done like this:

```js
// .storybook/main.js

module.exports = {
  // Your Storybook configuration

  webpackFinal: (config) => {
    config.resolve.alias['path/to/original/useConnectionStatus'] = require.resolve('../__mocks__/useConnectionStatus.js');
    return config;
  },
};
```

Now, decorate your previews with our new decorator, and you will be able to set configuration for every specific story separately.

```js
// inside your story
Story.parameters = {
  offline: true
}
```